# How to get Header In formation form ListBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

When I tap on listBox item i get a SubItem in "selectionChanged" event. I need to get Title as well. How i can achieve it?

```
public class Data
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }

    public Data()
    {
        SubItems = new List<SubItem>();   
    }    
}

<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" Grid.Row="0">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Padding="5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageSource}" Padding="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                                   
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubItemTitle}" Margin="0,0,12,0" Padding="10" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SelectionChanged` event, you can retrieve your ListBox by casting the `sender` parameter. From there, you can retrieve your Data object by casting the datacontext:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = (ListBox)sender;

    var data = (Data)listBox.DataContext;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under your `selectionChanged`event try this :

```
string text = (listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString(); //listBox is the name of the Listbox
```

a better reference could be this:

[Getting selected item string from bound ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200945/)

Hope it helps!